# Как можно понять куда утекает свободное место на диске?

Tags: windows, администрирование, файловая-система

В общем, на диске C пропадает куда-то свободное место.

Ничего в этот момент не устанавливается.

Мне хочется знать, что за программа и куда она пишет.

Можно ли какой-нибудь утилитой это узнать?

Я понимаю, что система может качать обновления, но пропадает свободное место ГБами...

Грешил на Outlook, но в настройках стоит другой диск для кеша.

Comment: filemon/procmon попробуйте

Comment: В крайнем случае можно написать свою утилиту, которая будет периодически мониторить размер папок и оповещать о серьёзном увеличении размера той или иной папки.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, как я понимаю в этих программах нужно мониторить глазками, а мне бы не помешал бы какой-нибудь лог. Какая программа куда за день чего записала.

Comment: Записала, потом стерла, потом снова записала... Суммарно занято на диске ноль, а в логах - 10 гигов. Сомнительно что такое есть

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов появятся кандидаты на изучение.

Comment: Через filemon они и так появятся

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов добавьте как ответ с примером, как ее правильно настроить, что бы вычислить виновников.

Comment: Может `windirstat`? Прогу не покажет, но увидишь какая папка забивается.

Answer (score 0):

для визуального наблюдения очень удобен SpaceSniffer
после окончания сканирования - он "переводится" в режим онлайн и постоянно обновляет картинку